# HttpContext.User.Identities has the same Identity twice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver3

I have configured a .NET MVC application to authenticate against a separately running Identity Server (IdentityServer3). I have configured OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications.SecurityTokenValidate() to place the user's claims into the AuthenticationTicket. Everything seems to be working as expected. The first time I access a page in the MVC app I get the Log In screen and after logging in I am redirected to the requested page.

But, when I look at the HttpContext.User (using a breakpoint in my override of CheckAccessAsync()) it has 2 identities. Looking closer I can see that both identities are the same, and that accessing the Claims property returns all of the claims twice.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have figured out what this issue is. I had configured the Authentication Server and the MVC app to use the same client, which actually caused other problems.

When I changed the Authentication Server to use its own client, the HttpContext.User in the MVC app still has 2 Identities but the Claims collection are not duplicated. I'm guessing that the Claims collection only contain the claims for the client that is accessing the collection. But I be totally sure since both clients return the same Claims collections.